# How do I pass the database id from flask html into a post form with python

Tags: python, html, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

UPDATE:
I think my question is too confusing.  To sum it up without all of the junk below.  How can I pass a parameter in an HTML link into the `POST` function of my python file?  I need that HTML parameter to be part of my commit to the database.  My searching so far has not been successful.

I have populated an html page `event_details.html` with all the table `events` entries that have a matching id for table `events_id` row.  In this page, I then have a link button to add another html page `add_events_details.html` to add a new entry to the database.

This link takes the user to another page with a wtform and I would like to pass the form the same `events_id` database row that is being matched to save the user entering this data.

So, the setup is, I pass the event_id of the entry to the `add_events_details.html`.  But I can only pass this `event_id` to the `get` and not the `post` function, and it is in the post function where I need the `event_id` data so I can add it to the database.

How can I pass that event_id into my views.py `post` function so I can then add it to the database?  Thank you in advance.

**event_details.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1>{{ current_user }}</h1>
    <p> This is the event details page </p>
    <a href="{{url_for('events.add_event_details', event_id=event_id)}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button">Add Schedule</a>
</div>      
....more code... to show entries
```

**add_event_details.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1>{{ current_user }}</h1>
    <p> This is the event details page </p>
    <a href="{{url_for('events.add_event_details', event_id=event_id)}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button">Add Schedule</a>
</div>
```

And the views.py is

```
class AddEventDetailsView(MethodView):

    decorators = [login_required]
    template_file = 'add_event_details.html'
    form_class = EventForm

    def get(self, event_id):
        return render_template(self.template_file, form=self.form_class())

    def post(self):
        form = self.form_class()
        print(form.errors)

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            #  I added this print to find out its type
            print(type(form.events_id.data))
            # This form returns the class model, so I just have to ask it for the \
            #  specific column that I want it to return

            # events_id = form.events_id.data.id
            user_id = current_user.id # This assumes that the person logged in is the company
            eventdetails = Eventdetails(
                schedule_name=form.schedule_name.data,
                event_id=event_id,
                user_id=user_id,
                naics=form.naics.data
            )
            print(f"The user id is {user_id}")
            db.session.add(eventdetails)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Thank you for registering your event.")
            return redirect(url_for('events.event_details', event_id=event_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out.  I can just pass the same parameter into my `POST` request and use it that way and it works fine.

So, instead of

```
def get(self, event_id):
```

I just can do

```
def post(self, event_id):
```